Housed/closed stringer staircase renovation: which option seems most sensible?
Our 1st-to-2nd-floor staircase is straight, encased on 2 sides its entire length, and consists of 13 steps. It has MDF treads that are soaked with pet urine and warped in some places. The risers are solid 1x pine. Both the treads and risers are slotted into dados in the stringers from underneath, then secured with wedges/shims. There is no center stringer. Drywall covers the back of the stringers, forming a ceiling to the basement steps just below.
I sawed the top step in half and removed it to examine how the steps were installed. Here's a picture of the step, with the riser on the right. I believe the 2x4 was installed to give some more support to the drywall.
As I see it, there are four ways to go forward with replacing these stairs.
1. Hire a carpenter
I can already hear some of you yelling. Yes, it's the obvious option, and I'm not ruling it out just yet, but seeing as they would almost certainly suggest replacing the staircase entirely, this would most likely exceed our current budget (assuming $5-10K+).
2. New treads, new risers, support bracing
This is my preferred option. Here's the rough plan:
Set up scaffolding over the basement steps and remove the drywall from under the stairs. The basement is unfinished anyway. While removing the drywall can potentially be avoided*, the scaffolding cannot, which annoys me.
Then for each step:

Remove the tread.
Remove the 2x4 from its current position (cutting existing nails/screws).
Install a support brace using the existing 2x4 (shortened by 1.5") and reorient it such that it acts as a joist for the tread. Frame it on either side by 2 triangles of new 3/4" plywood, and add a 2x6 behind the riser for extra support, also flush with the bottom of the tread. The 2x4/2x6 would be glued and screwed to the plywood, then the whole assembly would be glued and screwed into the stringers. This way the new riser and tread get support they'd otherwise lose from the dados, and we don't die trying to use the stairs. Here's a visual.
Remove the riser.
Remove the next tread to make room.
Install the new riser on the first step and nail/glue into place.
Install the new tread on the first step.
Repeat above for all remaining steps.
(Optional) Replace the drywall.

*It would also be possible to not remove the drywall at the beginning, but far more difficult. I'd need to cut a 41-degree miter in its bottom-facing long edge of each 2x4 support board and move it toward the back of the tread, such that the miter mates flush with the drywall. Then I'd need to screw the drywall into the 2x4 once the support brace is in place before moving onto the next step. That's a lot of back and forth, and doesn't eliminate the need for a scaffold.
3. New treads, new risers, use the dados
Basically take down the drywall and install new treads/risers in the exact same way that the stairs were originally installed. The only reason I prefer option 2 over this one is that I can do option 1 a step or two at a time, leaving the stairs functional for my family. I don't see that really happening with this one, so I'd feel time pressure.

Set up scaffolding over the basement steps and remove the drywall from under the stairs.
Demo the existing treads/risers.
Clean up the existing dados in case they get damaged.
Slot the new treads/risers into place, securing them with heavily glued wedges along the way.
(Optional) Replace the drywall.

#4. Retrofit treads/risers
My least favorite option, but it's there.

Sand the MDF treads (ew) to level them out a little. With a respirator.
Seal the MDF treads with Kilz 1-2-3 to contain the pet urine smell.
Saw the nose off each tread.
Install one support brace in the top step to make up for the fact that I sawed it in half.
Install retrofit treads and risers atop existing.

It's my least favorite because the awful, pee-soaked MDF doesn't go away, and I'd be concerned that the rise/run of the steps would be different due to adding the retrofit material, and I don't want people tripping. I'd also have to swap the 14 red oak treads that I already bought from F&D (not close) with retrofit ones, which is a minor annoyance. Finally, I'd have to buy new risers, whereas I already have the material in my basement now for new ones (whole 3/4" birch plywood sheet). That said, it might be the fastest.
What are your thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Pic summary:
Whole stairway
^(Yes, I know I need to run the ethernet through the wall; I'm getting to it, OK?)
How the stairs are currently structured
Top tread sawn in half
Inside top step
Proposed support brace

Are you sure that's a dado cut into the stringer, and not simply a skirting board?  It's a bit difficult to tell from the photo—kinda looks like 2 layers to me.

I thought so, too, initially. It's all one piece with routed dados. Notice how the grain is perfectly parallel; that's highly unlikely to happen with two layers. I will say that the tread dado in the picture split when I forcefully removed the tread, giving it the appearance of two layers. When I pulled it back, the split veered off in a random direction.

Were the treads nailed in from the sides of the stringer?

Yes, they were. Took a bit of elbow grease to get them out. I then either cut them flush with a multitool or, uh, violently pulled the heads through the stringer with nail-pulling pliers.

Could you not just screw some blocking to the stringers to support new treads that don't need to be inserted into the dadoes?

That's precisely what all of Option #2 is. I called it bracing instead of blocking, but same concept. I included a visual: https://i.imgur.com/mNl8x4z.png.

Yes.  That is what I'd personally do, in order to avoid having to hire a carpenter.  You may even find that there's sufficient "slop" to be able to insert a tread into the dado on one side and shift it over a little bit into the opposite dado, to avoid a gap.  But you'd still need the blocking to actually provide support.

You are right in that a carpenter will suggest that you replace the whole thing. A carpenter can cut new stringers and assemble that stair quicker than it will take them to cut and retrofit parts. At the end you'll end up paying less money (materials are way cheaper than the carpenter's time), and end up with a better stair.
I've encountered that type of stair you are dealing with a couple of times while doing remodels, and both times the client asked me to repair them, to then change their mind and ask me to build a new one when they saw how much more expensive the repair was going to be.
That is not to say that the only option is to hire a carpenter. If you don't have the money, you don't have the money and that's that. Building a stair can be a DIY project, but it does take some skill and should not be your first carpentry project. Demo the whole thing, install a scaffold, get a framing square and a circular saw, and give yourself time. Plenty of videos online on how to build a stair.

Thank you. All makes sense. I'll at least get a quote. Any tips for accessing the 2nd floor between demo and getting the stringers up? I guess a ladder on the scaffold lol. Asking mainly for my wife and 3 cats.

Yes, I just put an extension ladder. Practice cutting stringers before you demo the old stairs and have sub-treads (treads made out of plywood) that you can screw in place so that people can go up and down. Then you remove each of the plywood treads one at a time and install the hardwood treads. Or you can use sub-treads and sub-risers.

Great ideas. Thank you! I'm reading through the NYS 2020 Uniform code section 1011 on stairways and tried a few calculators. Compliance of the existing staircase seems a bit dubious. Probably going to end up being a longer run when I'm done, provided I can maintain a 36" landing. (For reference, the existing stairs measure 101.25" from finished floor to finished floor, with a 114 11/16" total run and 13 steps including only the top landing. New stairs will include 3/4" hardwood at the top, so 102.5" total rise.)
